# Sum of the series. What's wrong with this Python code?

Tags: python, debugging, sum-of-digits

I'm trying to write a program to find a sum of all multiples of 3 below given n.
So far I came up with this solution (using formula for arithmetic series):

```
def sumof3(n):
    n = int((n-1)/3)
    return int((n/2)*(6+3*(n-1)))
```

It works pretty well but for some reason starts to fail with large numbers. For example, for n = 232471924
the return value is 9007199280122284, while it should be 9007199280122283.

Can anybody advise where's a bug here?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has arbitrary-precision integers but standard limited (double) precision floats.  In Python 3, the division of two integers with `/` produces a float, which means (e.g.) that

```
>>> 10**50/10**25
1e+25
>>> int(10**50/10**25)
10000000000000000905969664
```

but if we work purely with integers using `//`, we get:

```
>>> 10**50//10**25
10000000000000000000000000
```

In your code, both `(n-1)/3` and `(n/2)` will produce float output, which means that you've only got ~18 digits or so of precision.  If we rework your function to work purely with integers:

```
def sumof3b(n):
    n = (n-1)//3
    return (6+3*(n-1))*n//2
```

Then we get agreement for the low values:

```
>>> all(sumof3(n) == sumof3b(n) for n in range(10**7))
True
```

but at high values we preserve the precision:

```
>>> n = 232471924
>>> sumof3(n) # bad
9007199280122284
>>> sumof3b(n) # good
9007199280122283
```

[Here we can reorder to make sure we're not losing any fractional data, but I sometimes find the [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) module comes in handy too.]

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a [round-off error](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html):

> *Squeezing infinitely many real numbers into a finite number of bits requires an approximate representation. Although there are infinitely many integers, in most programs the result of integer computations can be stored in 32 bits. In contrast, given any fixed number of bits, most calculations with real numbers will produce quantities that cannot be exactly represented using that many bits. Therefore the result of a floating-point calculation must often be rounded in order to fit back into its finite representation. This rounding error is the characteristic feature of floating-point computation.*

You'll get close enough to where you want to be by doing the following:

```
def sumof3(n):
    n = float((n-1)/3)
    return int((n/2)*(6+3*(n-1)))
```

Or if you want to be more precise:

```
def sumof3(n):
    n = float((n-1)/3)
    return float((n/2)*(6+3*(n-1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just too big for `int`

```
import sys
print int(sys.maxint)
print int(sys.maxint*2)
```

For me it prints

```
2147483647
-2
```

Dumb me! Misunderstud the question! Sorry!

Comment: Hmm, must be implementation-specific behavior. On CPython 2.7.2, I get `2147483647` and
`4294967294` when I run that.

Comment: Kevin. I was getting the same untile i added int() to prints. At first it was `print sys.maxint*2`.Did you do that?

Comment: Yes, I've got my `int()`s in place. [here](http://ideone.com/MXHYHB) is what I'm seeing.

Comment: `9007199163886320` in 2.7, `9007199280122284` in 3.4.0.

Comment: Oooh dumb me! I was really thinking that op's problem was completly different result (because number is too big) bot actually it's just rounding problem...
And about our case... I have to agree it should be implementaition-specific behaivor

Comment: At some point Python started using ints and longs interchangeably, converting to long automatically whenever the result didn't fit an int. I'm not sure which version that was. Python 3 eliminates the distinction altogether.